# AlertView in Else Statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hope you can help me. How i can show a alertView with else statement. in my example i check if textfields are empty. When they empty they will fill with user textinput. Now i will show a alertview if all the textfields filled with text. Thanks
                                                                                        `} else if werttxt15.text.isEmpty {
            werttxt15.text = mylabel2.text
        } else if werttxt16.text.isEmpty {
            werttxt16.text = mylabel2.text
        } else if werttxt17.text.isEmpty {
            werttxt17.text = mylabel2.text
        } else if werttxt18.text.isEmpty {
            werttxt18.text = mylabel2.text
        } else if werttxt19.text.isEmpty {
            werttxt19.text = mylabel2.text
        } else {  **ALERTVIEW**       }`

Comment: I would not use `UIAlertView` since iOS8+ (it still works but deprecated), and I would go for the much safer `UIAlertController` instead; btw your `if...else...` statement is logically incorrect, I would set up a `BOOL` with value `TRUE` at the beginning, and if any of your fields would be empty the value should be changed to `FALSE`; then you'll need to present your alert controller only if the value is `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks. I will test that.How i implement the UIAlertController in if ....else. Can you give me a example. I`m really new in swift :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward. Just add the following short example code in within your else-statement:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your title", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This assumes this code is run within a UIViewController instance. If not, you have to reference a target viewController on which to present the UIAlertController on.

Read more here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/